# How do I correctly format the unknown date which is probably wrong in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

[image: table of data]

I have this above data set in which i am pretty sure the signup_date column is wrongly formatted as it doesn't make sense for the years to be in future as the data belongs to years 2019-2021. How do i identify where it went wrong and correct it?

This error can be seen in a chunk of rows and years are in series with in between chunks having relevant year i.e(2019,2020,2021)

Comment: you will need to see the source data(before it is opened in Excel)

Comment: i was just given this excel and nothing else as this is part of an assignment, I will not have access to source data, it was mentioned the data was from years 2019/20/21

Comment: Once it is converted by excel the data is corrupt as excel will change it to a double and there is no way to reliably know what it should have been without seeing the source data that filled the column.

Comment: Is the actual file a csv or txt file?

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for the response, will try reaching out to the organizer

Comment: yes, but the original file you got from them(before it was opened in Excel), is it a csv or txt file?

Comment: This is the actual data, .xlsx file (before it was opened in excel)

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do.  It will need to be fixed at the source.

Comment: Is this an homework assignment? I suppose there is nothing wrong with how excel is interpreting the data but rather the errors were deliberately introduced and you are required to use excel functions such as IF and YEAR to generate a new column with all corrected dates, based on the assumption that at some point, the capturing computer's date was set to 2064 instead of 2019.

Comment: @ExcelEverything I have considered this possibility but didn't find any possible solution. if the computer date was set to some arbitrary number, how do you suggest going about it?

Comment: I think that is the part of the assignment you must figure out for yourself. What have you tried? You must figure out a way to distinguish between legitimate dates and wrong dates, then a mathematical formula to correct the wrong dates (assuming the date error is the same for all sections of data and not random). You can edit you question with formulae you have tried and ask specific questions, but SU cannot do your assignment for you.